# What JavaScript engine does Apple's Safari browser use?

Tags: javascript, safari, javascript-engine

I found out from the Internet that Google Chrome uses **V8** and Firefox uses **SpiderMonkey** to compile JavaScript to machine code. What JavaScript engine does Safari browser use then?

Comment: WebKit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> - **JavaScriptCore** is the built-in JavaScript engine for WebKit.
> - JavaScriptCore is often referred with different names, such as **​SquirrelFish** and ​**SquirrelFish Extreme**. Within the context of Safari, **Nitro** and **Nitro Extreme** are also commonly used. However, the name of the project and the library is always JavaScriptCore.

Source: https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore